# Reading and checking multiple values at once from another google sheet using if()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set up a script that fetches values from another sheet and compares them (using `if()`) to values entered through `ui.prompts` in the active sheet.

The user needs to enter values in the `ui.prompt` that need to match values held in another sheet, if they match then it runs another function.

I have written the below code which unfortunately doesn't work - I believe there may be a few issue with the way I have written the `if()` and `for()` functions but I can't put my finger on it - can anyone help please?

The code is as below:

```
function firstOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1HsE2Smq6iSkNxvonEOTOmz54MfzWJduWoNA5P6xaKxk").getSheetByName('Users');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("BALANCE SHEET");
  var getAccNo = ui.prompt('Login', 'Please enter your account number:', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var getSgEm = ui.prompt('Login', 'And your subscriber email address:', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var sgCode = ui.prompt('Login', 'Finally, your subscription code:', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  sh.getRange('AI30').setValue(getAccNo);
  sh.getRange('AI31').setValue(getSgEm);
  sh.getRange('AI32').setValue(sgCode);
  var accNo = sh.getRange('AI30').getValue(); // user entered acc no
  var sgEmail = sh.getRange('AI31').getValue(); // user entered subscriber email
  var subCode = sh.getRange('AI32').getValue(); // user entered subscriber code (as on email)

  for (var i = 1; i < lastRow; i++)
  {
    if (subCode == values[i][3] && accNo == values[i][4] && sgEmail == values[i][5])
    {
      ui.alert('Success', 'You have entered details correctly', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
      sortOutSheets();
    }
    else
    {
      ui.alert('Failed', 'The details were incorrect.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The return for `ui.prompt('Login', 'Please enter your account number:', ui.ButtonSet.OK);`
is not just a value. It is an object called [Class PromptResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response)

**Methods**

[getResponseText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response#getResponseText())

[getSelectedButton()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response#getSelectedButton())

ui was undefined in your code

```
function firstOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1HsE2Smq6iSkNxvonEOTOmz54MfzWJduWoNA5P6xaKxk").getSheetByName('Users');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("BALANCE SHEET");
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();//this defines ui
  var getAccNo = ui.prompt('Login', 'Please enter your account number:', ui.ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText();
  var getSgEm = ui.prompt('Login', 'And your subscriber email address:', ui.ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText()
  var sgCode = ui.prompt('Login', 'Finally, your subscription code:', ui.ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText();
  sh.getRange('AI30').setValue(getAccNo);
  sh.getRange('AI31').setValue(getSgEm);
  sh.getRange('AI32').setValue(sgCode);
  var accNo = sh.getRange('AI30').getValue(); // user entered acc no
  var sgEmail = sh.getRange('AI31').getValue(); // user entered subscriber email
  var subCode = sh.getRange('AI32').getValue(); // user entered subscriber code (as on email)
  for (var i = 1; i < lastRow; i++) {
    if (subCode == values[i][3] && accNo == values[i][4] && sgEmail == values[i][5]) {
      ui.alert('Success', 'You have entered details correctly', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
      sortOutSheets();
    } else {
      ui.alert('Failed', 'The details were incorrect.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    }
  }
}
```